# Hash based Dom manuplation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a hash based url (e.g. `www.dummy.com#/hello/welcome`), I want to trigger javascript code when `/welcome` changes to `/start` (e.g. `www.dummy.com#/hello/start`).

Following is the code I've tried but isn't working.

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",function() {
alert('The hash has changed!');
},false);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) instead of the outdated and not very robust `hashchange` event

Answer (score 0):

The hashchange event only happens when the hash changes, so if you just type the URL and hit enter nothing happens. Therefore you need to handle more cases: 1) the hash changes, 2) user types URL and 3) the history forward/back button is used to navigate to the page.

```js
const eitherhashorload = e => {
  let hash = location.hash.substring(1);
  if(!hash){
    location.hash = 'welcome';
    return;
  }
  console.log(hash);
};

window.addEventListener("hashchange", eitherhashorload);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', eitherhashorload);
```

```html
<p><a href="#start">Start</a> - <a href="#end">End</a></p>
```